# area tag/ not clickable in firefox MAC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, area

Hi I made a image map with 2 clickable areas. (The Netherlands and South Africa)
It works fine in **Google chrome, Edge, Internet Explorere 11, Safari and mobile/tablet browser and chrome.**

But if I open my page: http://www.fruitconneqt.jevdopilot.nl/index.php/teest/
in firefox on my MAC I can't click on the Netherlands or South Africa.

I really don't know why this is not working... so I hope maybe you know what I can change to make this work in mozilla firefox for MAC.

Thanks...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<title>relaties</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="js/ios-orientationchange-fix.min.js"></script>
<!--Fireworks CS5 Dreamweaver CS5 target.  Created Wed Dec 02 16:20:39 GMT+0100 (CET) 2015-->
<style>
 body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 }
 h1 {
  font-size: 20px;
 }
 div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
 }
 img[usemap] {
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
 }

 </style>
 <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/agency.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kaushan+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,100,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]AFRIKA 917,563,1062,614| NL 835,161,1000,240-->
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
 <div>
<img name="relaties" src="img/relaties.jpg" width="1909" height="832" border="0" id="relaties" usemap="#m_relaties" alt="" /><map name="m_relaties" id="m_relaties">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseSix" class="page-scroll" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix">
            <area shape="rect" coords="896,556,1072,632" href="#collapseSix" alt="" />
        </a>
       
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" class="page-scroll" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
            <area shape="rect" coords="816,155,1016,253" href="#collapseOne" alt="" />
            </a>
        
</map>
</div>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    <div class="item active">
                      <div id="wrap text-center">
                
            </div>
                    </div>
                    
                  </div>
                
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="container text-left">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title  text-left">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"><strong>The Netherlands</strong><span class="caret" ></span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body  text-left"> <p><img src="img/logo_fruitconneqt_klein.jpg" width="15%" > &nbsp; &nbsp;Fruit Conneqt &nbsp; - &nbsp;<a href="http://www.fruitconneqt.nl" target="_blank">Bekijk de website</a></p><hr>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- FRANCE -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-left">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"><strong>France</strong><span class="caret"></span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body text-left">
                    <p>Honey Crunch <a href="#" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- ITALY -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-left">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"><strong>Italy</strong><span class="caret"></span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body text-left">
                    <p>Mazzoni <a href="#" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- CHILE -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-left">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour"><strong>Chile</strong><span class="caret"></span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body text-left">
                    <p>CopeFrut <a href="#" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- NEW ZEALAND -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-left">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFive"><strong>New Zealand</strong><span class="caret"></span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body text-left">
                    <p>Taylor New Zealand <a href="#" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!-- SOUTH AFRICA -->
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title text-left">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseSix"><strong>South Africa</strong><span class="caret"></span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseSix" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body text-left">
                    <p><img src="img/capesupra.jpg" width="15%">&nbsp; &nbsp;Cape Supra &nbsp; - &nbsp;<a href="http://www.capesupra.co.za" target="_blank">Bekijk de website</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <section id="services">
        
    </section>
    
    </div>
            </div>
            
        </div>
<script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
 <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/classie.js"></script>
    <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/agency.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.rwdImageMaps.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('img[usemap]').rwdImageMaps();
 
 
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are an awful lot of errors showing in the console. Fix them and your issue may be resolved.

Comment: @Sexy Turnip Thanks for your reaction. Really? Where did you see that? So I can take a look. Because the scrolling is also not working on Apple divices...

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools and look in the console

Comment: Thanks, I did fixed some errors. But some of the errors I don't understand to fix it. And scrolling to the open panel/collapse still nog working in firefox or on apple devices :( Do you know if it is possible that apple doesn't support this or that there is an conflict with toggle + scroll-page (to top of the panel with information) ?